# Xamarin.iOS Side of Application, Ignoring Blocks of Code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My `Xamarin.iOS` side of the application is just simply ignoring the images list for the `MainPage` Carousel.

I've set

```
Forms.SetFlags("CarouselView_Experimental");
```

In App Delegate

Android run's fine without any hitches.

Note: These are loaded from a `WebPage`

Code in Question:

```
//Breaks
  InitializeComponent();
//Skips IOS only
 var imagez = new List<string>
 {
 "https://Site/Pic1.jpg","https://Site/Pic2.jpg","https://Site/Pic3.jpg","https://Site/Pic4.jpg","https://Site/Pic5.jpg"
 };
  //Skips IOS only
  MainCarouselView.ItemsSource = imagez;
```

If any more context is needed let me know.

Comment: Also ```Forms.SetFlags("CarouselView_Experimental");``` Is set before ```Forms.Init()```

Comment: What do you mean by skipped, Have you checked by debugging those lines or do you mean that the Images are not displayed in the View? Also Provide where is the MainCarouselView

Comment: So, Is your issue fixed by adding the Forms.SetFlags("CarouselView_Experimental"); after Forms.Init() ?

Comment: If I debug on them Its just skipped it never hits the break point, Just simply skips its and moves on, on a normal run just nothings displayed, I can get it to break if I Set the ItemSource before the Initialize But then the Initialize is skipped, As for The Flags issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/introduction It has to be set before Forms.Init()

Comment: Are you using `Xamarin Forms CollectionView`? Or `AlexRainman CarouselView`?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms CarouselView? [OfficialDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/)

Comment: @Someguy Hi , could you share a sample project link here , I will check it in my local site .

Comment: Honestly Can't reproduce it, I tried but cant reproduce it, Also cant find anything differing from a normal project,It just seems like some Web Images arent getting loaded On IOS, With this however its just not Initialising the CarouselView

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using The Alexrainmen CarouselView instead

[The GitHub](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView)

It works perfectly.